# Seaborn grouped barplot with total values instead of mean

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, grouped-bar-chart

I got a question on how to organize my data to make a barplot with seaborn.
My data input looks like the following

```
influencer  platform  reach
person a    instagram 10000
person b    instagram 5000
person a    instagram 8000
person a    youtube   13000
```

What I need is a barplot that shows the sum of the reach per category per influencer.

Basically I'm getting quite close with seaborn, but it shows the mean of the reach column, not the total

```
sns.barplot(x='influencer', y='reach', data=df, hue='platform')
```

I tried arranging my inputs with a crosstab

```
pd.crosstab(df['influencer'], df['platform'])
```

but instead the totals I get the sum of entries.

Feels like I'm close, but I can't get it fully done.
Could you please help me?

Comment: `per category` you meant `per platform `, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the data, use the `estimator` parameter to change how [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) aggregates the categories:

> **`estimator`** : Statistical function to estimate within each categorical bin.

```
sns.barplot(data=df, x='influencer', y='reach', hue='platform',
            estimator=sum, ci=None)
```

[image]

Or if you still want to compute the sums manually, use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
sns.barplot(data=df.groupby(['influencer', 'platform'], as_index=False)['reach'].sum(),
            x='influencer', y='reach', hue='platform')
```